# Get the output of another url and store it in a variable, while maintaining session

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, development, curl

Scenario:

1. User is posting an ajax request to Joomla site (via [com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)).
2. Inside the called method, I want to retrieve the entire html output
       of a known Joomla submenu (let's say /contact). The joomla submenu is only accessible to a different user than the one currently logged in.
3. The method then returns the html back to the user.

OK, I can do #1 and #3, no problem. How can I do #2 ?

Things I've explored:

- Posting via cURL - I could not find a way to maintain session
  variables and surpass Joomla's CSRF protection mechanism.
- Using `ob_start`, then using the `redirect` method of `JApplication`. This sends only the redirect headers.
- Using JApplication->login to impersonate a user. This solves just a part of the problem. I am only mentioning it because if someone posts an answer via cURL, it'd have to tackle the authentication problem too.

"Solutions" that will not work (to save you some time):

- `require` / `include` X file: No, because I want an entire url (which
  may contain multiple components/modules)
- Have the user directly call the url (in this case /contact): No, for
  various business logic rules. Let's say for simplicity that the
  returned html output is "enriched" before being sent back.

Comment: +1 for using `com_ajax`, doesn't often happen :)

Answer (score 1):

I had partial success with the following, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854089/1543677) answer mainly:

```
<?php
function retrieveURL($relativeURL){
    $uname = "user";    //this is the privileged user to the relative url we want
    $upswd = "pass";
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $prefix = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    $url_get_key = $prefix.$domain."index.php?option=com_users"; 

    //GET return & key
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_get_key );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');   //as far as i understand, this stores a *new* session to a cookie file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

    $results = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"return\" value=\"(.*)\" />)siU", $results, $matches1);   //Should not be needed if username and password are correct
    preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"(.*)\" value=\"1\" />(.*)</fieldset>)iU", $results, $matches2); //Same as above

    // POST
    $url_post = $prefix.$domain."index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login";
    $postdata = "username=".urlencode($uname)."&password=".urlencode($upswd)."&return=".urlencode($matches1[1][0])."&".urlencode($matches2[1][0])."=1";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $results1 = curl_exec($ch);

    $url_data = $prefix.$domain.$relativeURL;   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);   //Now we can retrieve the proper url

    $results2 = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $results2;   //could probably use a bit more error checking
}
?>
```

This retrieves the html of the output page with the credentials of the privileged user. Now, if I could somehow keep the session variables of the previous user, or inject them to the new session, all would be perfect. From what I understand though, what I am trying to do may be called "Session poisoining" :)